# VBA, Moving Pivot, unable to get the rowrange property of the pivottable class

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that updates my pivot from last row up 52 rows, It has worked on another pivot of mine. However on this pivot I am getting a `unable to get the rowrange property of the pivottable class` error on line `For n = ws.PivotTables("scencount").RowRange.Count To 1 Step -1`. My pivot is on my active sheet and my datasource of the pivot is on another.

```
 Sub MovingPivotirworst()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim dtTop As Date
        Dim i As Integer, n As Long

        Const NumWeeks = 52  'Change this to set weeks range


        Set ws = ActiveSheet

        'reset the pivot filters
        ws.PivotTables("scencount").PivotFields("businessDate").ClearAllFilters
        'remove blank values
        ws.PivotTables("scencount").PivotFields("businessDate").PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False


        'find the date entry in 50 places from bottom.
        i = 0
        For n = ws.PivotTables("scencount").RowRange.Count To 1 Step -1
            If i = NumWeeks Then
                dtTop = ws.PivotTables("scencount").RowRange.Cells(n).Value
                Exit For
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next n

        ws.PivotTables("scencount").PivotFields("businessDate").PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlAfterOrEqualTo, Value1:=Format(dtTop, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
    End Sub
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks.